# Understanding what is represented by function pointers to a block of hex

Tags: disassembly, assembly, binary-analysis, static-analysis, hex

I'm working on a disassembly project for my class where I'm trying to bypass a license check, but when I throw the executable into Binary Ninja this is what I see:

[image: Function pointers within binary ninja]

And when I look at those pointers, they are all pointing to the same block of hex:
[image: Block of hex]

I'm not sure what to make of it, or even how to interpret it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an import table. I.e. it holds the information about the functions which are called from the other dynamic libraries.